# SQL: Group by for last 3 months and last 5 months respectively

Tags: mysql, sql

Based on a table of the sales from different time periods, I am trying to calculate aggregated values from 2 different time periods: (1) Sales where date > '2018-11-26'  and (2) sales where date > '2018-09-26'

```
create table revenue (sales float, date_time datetime) 
insert into revenue (sales,date_time) values (300, '2018-09-01')
insert into revenue (sales,date_time) values (200, '2018-10-01')
insert into revenue (sales,date_time) values (300, '2018-11-01')
insert into revenue (sales,date_time) values (400, '2019-01-01')
insert into revenue (sales,date_time) values (500, '2019-02-01')
```

I've seen other solutions that uses case when for time periods, however the difference in this case is that the time periods are not mutually exclusive.

The query I want should work something like this:

```
select sum(sales) from revenue
group by date_time where date_time > '2018-11-26',  
date_time where date_time > '2018-09-26'
```

Comment: well that's something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use union all

```
select 'p1' as prd , sum(sales) from revenue
where date_time >= '2018-11-26'

union all
select 'p2', sum(sales) from revenue
where date_time > '2018-09-26'
```

or you can use `case when`

```
select case when date_time >= '2018-11-26' then 'p1'
              when date_time > '2018-09-26' 
              then 'p2' end as period, sum(sales) from revenue
              group by case when date_time >= '2018-11-26' then 'p1'
              when date_time > '2018-09-26' 
              then 'p2' end
```

Comment: the first solution works with the point being that date_time should not be between '2018-09-26' and '2018-11-26'. It should just be 2 different groups where the one shows summed for last 3 months and the other one sum for last 5 months.

Comment: @MathiasRa does it helps?

Comment: @MathiasRa i have edited condition hope both will work now btw if it helps mark it as accepted